# run a macro on particular cell selection using vbs

Tags: macros, vbscript, apache-poi, xls

I need to write a vbs that selects a cell and runs a macro on that cell
here's the code I found online(that doesnt work)

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 3).Select
xl.Run "'Book1.xls'!Calc"
```

I am creating this vbs in Eclips(Running this VBS through

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c RUN_MACRO.vbs "+xlsFile+" "+ macroName);
```

Still after running I get no error and no change in the excel as well.
Please help

Full Code for VBS for RUN_MACRO.vbs
Here Calc is the Macro name saved in some Module(as I created this macro(to multiply A2*B2) in Open Office and when I select a cell and run a macro,I the cell value gets changed)

```
Set xl = CreateObject(WScript.Arguments(0))
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(WScript.Arguments(1))
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 3).Select
Range("C5").Select
xl.Run "'Book1.xls'!Calc"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
wb.Close
xl.Quit
```

Method calling this vbs in my java file

```
public static void executeMacros(String xlsFile, String macroName){

          try{  
              Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c RUN_MACRO.vbs "+xlsFile+" "+ macroName);  

      }catch(Exception e)  
      { System.out.println(e);}  
     }
```

Comment: Please show the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few oddities in your VBS file. The first is that you are trying to create an object from an Excel file instead of from a Class. So the first thing that you need to do is `Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`.

Because you are doing `Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(WScript.Arguments(1))` and your second argument is the macro name the script is trying to open a workbook named "macroname".

You are also trying to select two different cells before actually executing the macro. So `ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 3).Select` doesn't seem necessary and wouldn't really work anyways.

The `xl.Run "'Book1.xls'!Calc"` actually needs to be in the format of `xl.Run "ModuleName.MacroName"`

You may need to use this code to update other cells. Therefore you may be interested in adding a third argument to the cell that actually needs to be updated.

Thus try this as your vbs:

```
WorkBookToOpen = WScript.Arguments(0)
MacroToRun = WScript.Arguments(1)
CellToUpdate = WScript.Arguments(2)

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(WorkBookToOpen)

xl.Range( CellToUpdate ).Select
xl.Run "Module1."  & MacroToRun
xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save
wb.Close
xl.Quit
```

And then change to:

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c RUN_MACRO.vbs "+xlsFile+" "+ macroName + " " + cellToUpdate);`

Comment: This is how I am calling it Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c RUN_MACRO.vbs "+xlsFile+" "+ macroName+" "+"ActiveSheet.Cells(3,3)");   and the vbs is same as you sugested

Comment: You do need the full path.  The script can be debugged by using the command prompt change directories to where the vbs file is then run cscript.exe run_macros.vbs c:\xlpath\xlfile.xlsx Calc C3.  As you can see the third parameter is just the name of the cell on the sheet. Thus your java call needs to simply be the name and not the cells argument that you are using. I hope that helps.

Comment: thanks tried running the script from cmd as suggested, Also changed my parameter to "C3" but got this error :D:\RUN_MACRO.vbs(5, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't
 create object: 'Excel.Application'.thanks for your quick response

Comment: I realized that I had OpenOffice installed on my machine,I ran the script at a system having MS Office, ran like a charm.Thanks :)

Comment: Just one more small question, Now I need to run a script that runs a macro but does not save the workbook, I understand that I can simply omit the line xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save but how shall I check whether the Macro actually ran? Is there any macro example that can help me do that?maybe something that doesnt change cell color/font? that doesnt need the cell parameter to work on

Comment: After the "set wb" line add xl.visible=true and yes omit the save line. Well probably help.